# spring integration CachingSessionFactory session pool clarification

Tags: spring-integration

We are using spring integration CachingSessionFactory to cache sftp sessions. All works fine but had one question about how does those sessions are being handles.

Say for eg, if my pool size is 10 and out of those 10 pool if one of the session is stale(may be disconnected to actual sftp server), does that stale session being thrown and replaced by another good one before being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your conclusion is correct. `CachingSessionFactory` is based on the `org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool` and the requested code looks like:

```
private T doGetItem() {
    T item = this.available.poll();
    if (item != null && logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Obtained " + item + " from pool.");
    }
    if (item == null) {
        item = this.callback.createForPool();
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Obtained new " + item + ".");
        }
        allocated.add(item);
    }
    else if (this.callback.isStale(item)) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Received a stale item " + item + ", will attempt to get a new one.");
        }
        doRemoveItem(item);
        item = doGetItem();
    }
    this.inUse.add(item);
    return item;
}
```

Please, refer to their source code for more info.